# Deploy of JAX-RS app with Tomcat, but required resource always not found

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

I've developed a RESTful service with JAX-RS, using Jersey libraries. I've builded and compiled it (with no errors) and I've deployed it with Tomcat 8.0.

But when I access to the service through the browser, always the same error:

```
Status HTTP 404 - Not Found

type Informe de estado

message Not Found

description The requested resource is not available

Apache Tomcat/8.0.21
```

I've already past several days struggling with this, and I can't find a solution. I've followed multiples tutorials, some of them very easy ones, but none of them got my service working.

I've tried using IntellJ Idea and Eclipse. You can download the project and try the service from my Github:

https://github.com/daniegarcia254/SmartCULM.git

There are two branches apart from the *master*, one for the [Eclipse project](https://github.com/daniegarcia254/SmartCULM/tree/develop_eclipse) and the another one for the [IntellJ Idea project](https://github.com/daniegarcia254/SmartCULM/tree/develop_intellij_idea).

Both projects use Maven repositories for the needed libraries that are in the respectives ***pom.xml***.

I think my final mistake is that I don't nail the **service URL**, but I've tried in a thousand different ways. Maybe I have the wrong structure of project or the wrong ***web.xml*** config, don't sure anymore about anythin!

For extra info, here the URL I'think should be the one valid to access the RESTful service once it's deployed:

http://localhost:8080/smartculm/api/service/noticias

Comment: I believe it is just the package name, not the class. It should be `<param-value>com.gps.service</param-value>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not positive, but I think that you might be missing some data in your web.xml file.  In the projects that I've worked on, I had to specify the class of my servlet and the location of my resource and application files.

```
<display-name> display-name </display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Some_Service_Name</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.resource.package.name</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.application.package.ApplicationClassName</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Some_Service_Name</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I believe that instead of "com.resource.package.name", you would probably use "main.java.rest.smartculm".  I don't see an application in your project, so I'm not sure what you would use.  I usually define my own application class by extending javax.ws.rs.core.Application.  I also put all of the files that you have in your webapp directory in the WebContent directory at the root of my project, instead of being in the src directory.

A reference that I used to get started was:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html

**Important:**
The complete path to a resource is based on the base URL and:

- *display*-name  -> configured in the `<display-name>` tag in the web.xml
- *url-pattern*   --> configured in the `<url-pattern>` tag in the web.xml
- *path_from_rest_class*  --> defined by the @Path annotations in your classes

> http://your_domain:port/display-name/url-pattern/path_from_rest_class

Comment: You were right about my missing Application class! Thanks!  P.D.: I've edited your answer with some more details in order to accept it =)

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad I was able to help. It can be frustrating getting a new web app project working.